# Recursive loop through Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion

So I can see the problem, I just don't know how to fix it. I've been all over the interwebz!

I don't know how you're supposed to move to the next entry in the object tree when the condition doesn't match. At the moment I'm just overloading the call stack.

```js
const myObject = {
  x: {
    y: {
      z: {
        e: 'ddfg'
      }
    }
  }
};
const param = Object.keys(myObject);

function traverse(target) {
  for (const key in target) {
    if (target[key] !== 'e') {
      traverse(target[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key, target[key]);
    }
  }
}

traverse(param);
```

If you could lend a hand that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues; you should be traversing over the object, not its keys, and you should be checking if `key === 'e'`, not `target[key] !== 'e'`. Also, you should check that `target[key]` is an object before attempting to traverse it:

```js
const myObject = {
  x: {
    y: {
      z: {
        e: 'ddfg'
      }
    }
  }
};

function traverse(target) {
  for (const key in target) {
    if (key !== 'e' && typeof target[key] === 'object') {
      traverse(target[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key, target[key]);
    }
  }
}

traverse(myObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time on that. That's certainly fixed the issue. It's a little confusing how it moves down through the object though. In the first instance x is the key, so when you call traverse and pass x in again shouldn't it go back to the start? I feel I am missing a key part of the knowledge behind it here I haven't been able to source online.

Comment: @LewisMorgans yes, in the first instance `x` is the key, but what is passed to the recursive call is `myObject['x']`, which is `y: { z: { e: 'ddfg'  } } }`, so in the next `for` loop the value of `key` is `y`. In situations like this I always find it useful to drop in a few `console.log` around the place to see what the variables are doing...

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the keys inside `traverse`, so don't extract an array of keys from the input beforehand.

Inside `traverse`, only make the recursive call if the nested value is an object (and not `null`):

```js
'use strict';

const myObject = {
  x: {
    y: {
      z: {
        e: 'ddfg'
      }
    }
  }
};

function traverse(target) {
  for (const key in target) {
    const value = target[key];
    if (key === 'e') {
      console.log(value);
    } else if (typeof value === 'object' && value) {
      // Nested object found, recurse:
      traverse(value);
    }
  }
}

traverse(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a generic `traverse` function?

```js
function* traverse (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const k in t)
        ( yield [k, t[k]]
        , yield *traverse(t[k])
        )
      break
    default:
      return
  }
}
```

This allows you to invert the control and decouple your filtering and and effect, keeping it separate from your traversal logic -

```js
for (const [k, v] of traverse(myObject))
  if (k == "e")
    console.log(v)
```

```js
"ddfg"
```

Verify the results in your browser below -

```js
function* traverse (t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const k in t)
        ( yield [k, t[k]]
        , yield *traverse(t[k])
        )
      break
    default:
      return
  }
}

const myObject = {
  x: {
    y: {
      z: {
        e: 'ddfg'
      }
    }
  }
}

for (const [k, v] of traverse(myObject))
  if (k == "e")
    console.log(v)
    
// ddfg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { x: { y: { z: { e: 'ddfg' } } } };

const r = objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ property }) => property === 'e',
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'entry'
})(data);

console.log(r);
// => [ [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'e' ], 'ddfg' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.9.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)